# Writing to outputfile within thread execution

Tags: c#

I have following code, but if I use `Console.ReadKey()` then the output is written to file once I close the console, but I have to press key to exit the app. If I comment the `Console.Readkey()` the code exit, but output file is blank, how can I write to output file and exit the application without any manual key press ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 1;

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Software\ThreadTest1\ServerList.txt");

        /*
        ServerList.txt has file windows server names in it
        */

        foreach (string linevalue in lines)
        {
            var value = i;
            var runningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fillServiceAccountDetailsinGrid(linevalue.ToString(), value));
            i = i + 1;
        }

        //  Console.ReadKey(); // if I uncomment this list, only then the output file has message written, but then console 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Software\ThreadTest1\Output_ServerList_Log2.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Error occurred on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Error occurred in module 'writetoDatabase' Description : " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Error occurred on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Error occurred in module 'writetoDatabase' Description : " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void fillServiceAccountDetailsinGrid(string srvName, int i)
{
    try
    {
        string path = @"C:\Software\ThreadTest1\" + srvName.ToString() + ".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Error occurred on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Error occurred in module 'writetoDatabase' Description : " + srvName.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Error occurred on : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Error occurred in module 'writetoDatabase' Description : " + srvName.ToString());
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Because your main thread doesn't wait for "runningtask" you are starting. Try Task.Wait method and see it it works.

Comment: I tried :var runningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fillServiceAccountDetailsinGrid(linevalue.ToString(), value));
                    runningTask.Wait();

Comment: Did not work :-(

Answer (score 1):

You are firing off Tasks asynchronously and not waiting for them to complete.

If you want synchronous concurrency try replacing your `foreach` loop with the following...

```
Parallel.For(0, lines.Length, (int lineId) =>
{
    fillServiceAccountDetailsinGrid(lines[lineId].ToString(), lineId);
});
```

...this will not return until all actions have completed.

Comment: There is no more likelihood of a file handle in use exception if you make the work concurrent as this is processing a list servers (unless there are duplicates in the list, but the intent here is clearly to kick the work off concurrently so this will need to be validated). Data can't be in the wrong order either - these are separate files being created.

Answer (score 0):

@Creyke is correct this is issue with task management .

```
List<Task> tasklist = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string linevalue in lines)
            {
                var value = i;
                tasklist.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fillServiceAccountDetailsinGrid(linevalue.ToString(), value)));
                i = i + 1;
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasklist.ToArray());
```

wating for all task will fix this.